# Can't find the package R in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting the error: package R does not exist
I have checked every post on here and I can't fix my r does not exist error
I see it is in the app/build/generated/source/ but it still says it doesn't exist when I build.
Help? D:

Comment: post some error log!

Comment: I have checked every answer there none of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have any compile errors in your code. Also check if you have imported the correct R check the package of the import. Is it your R or android's R or some other R. Clean build everything and check again.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that there are no errors in your resource files. And then delete your import android.R; statement in your class and build the project. It will automatically generate R.java.

Comment: what do you mean errors in my resource files?

Comment: there should not be a single error in any file of res folder. Means your all .xml files including manifest.xml should be error free so that R.java will be generated successfullly.

Comment: How do I check that tho is what I mean?

Comment: @joe sorry I did't get you

Comment: Dear friend, just check whether your res folder is not having red error mark, your import of R.java file is correct and if it is giving error then delete R.java and rebuild the project.